# Adaptivecards Action.submit - How to send email by clicking on submit?

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

My Luis Bot code:

```
public async Task ScheduleAnAppointmentIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{
    var replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();
    var json = await GetCardText1("scheduleappointment");
    //await context.PostAsync(json);
    AdaptiveCardParseResult cardParseResult = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(json);
    replyMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
    {
        Content = cardParseResult.Card,
        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
        Name = "Card"
    });
    await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);
}
public async Task<string> GetCardText1(string cardName)
{
    var path = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"/Dialogs/{cardName}.json");
    if (!File.Exists(path))
        return string.Empty;

    using (var f = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        return await f.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var message = await result;
    if (message.Value != null)
    {
        dynamic value = message.Value;
        string name = value.myName.ToString();
        string email = value.myEmail.ToString();
        string tel = value.myTel.ToString();
        string selectvalue = value.CompactSelectVal.ToString();
        string discussiondate = value.mydiscussiondate.ToString();
        string discussionduration = value.mydiscussionduration.ToString();

        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        message1.To.Add("XXXXXXXX@gmail.com");
        message1.Subject = "Interview Schedule request from" + name;
        message1.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("XXXXXXX@gmail.com");
        message1.Body = "Name:" + name + "\n Email:" + email + "\nPhone:" + tel + "\nCalltype:" + selectvalue + "\nDiscussion Date:" + discussiondate + "\nDiscussiona Duration:" + discussionduration;
        System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        smtp.Send(message1);
    }
}
```

It is a LUIS Bot with C#.

I can render the adaptive card nicely. When i click on submit i am expecting to get an email in my inbox rather i get the message "my bot is having issue". Please help me !

Answer (score 0):

> I can render the adaptive card nicely. When i click on submit i am expecting to get an email in my inbox rather i get the message "my bot is having issue".

It seems that you’d like to send an AdaptiveCard form Luis dialog and enable user to send an email by clicking AdaptiveCard submit button. Based on your requirement, I create and do a test with the following sample code, which work for me, you can refer to it.

*In RootDialog:*

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        if (activity.Value != null)
        {
            dynamic value = activity.Value;

            //please make sure you can extract all of these values (myName, myEmail ... mydiscussionduration etc) from activity.Value
            string name = value.myName.ToString();
            string email = value.myEmail.ToString();
            string tel = value.myTel.ToString();
            string selectvalue = value.CompactSelectVal.ToString();
            string discussiondate = value.mydiscussiondate.ToString();
            string discussionduration = value.mydiscussionduration.ToString();

            System.Net.Mail.MailMessage message1 = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            message1.To.Add("xxxx@hotmail.com");
            message1.Subject = "Interview Schedule request from" + name;
            message1.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("alexzwz1211@gmail.com");
            message1.Body = "Name:" + name + "\n Email:" + email + "\nPhone:" + tel + "\nCalltype:" + selectvalue + "\nDiscussion Date:" + discussiondate + "\nDiscussiona Duration:" + discussionduration;
            System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxx@gmail.com", "xxxx");
            smtp.Send(message1);
        }
        else
        {
            //forward to Luis dialog
            await context.Forward(new BasicLuisDialog(), AfterLuis, activity, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task AfterLuis(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }      
}
```

*In BasicLuisDialog:*

```
[LuisIntent("Greeting")]
public async Task GreetingIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{

    var replyMessage = context.MakeMessage();

    var json = await GetCardText1("scheduleappointment");
    //await context.PostAsync(json);
    AdaptiveCardParseResult cardParseResult = AdaptiveCard.FromJson(json);
    replyMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment()
    {
        Content = cardParseResult.Card,
        ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
        Name = "Card"
    });

    await context.PostAsync(replyMessage);

    //await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
}

public async Task<string> GetCardText1(string cardName)
{
    var path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"/Dialogs/{cardName}.json");
    if (!File.Exists(path))
        return string.Empty;

    using (var f = File.OpenText(path))
    {
        return await f.ReadToEndAsync();
    }
}
```

*scheduleappointment.json*

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.0",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "TextBlock",
      "size": "large",
      "weight": "bolder",
      "text": "This is Adaptive Card"
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "data": {
        "myName": "Fei Han",
        "myEmail": "feihan@xxx.com",
        "myTel": "xxxx",
        "CompactSelectVal": "val",
        "mydiscussiondate": "date",
        "mydiscussionduration": "duration"
      },
      "title": "Send Email"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Note:**

1)  You can do a test with above sample code, or compare it with your implementation

2)  You can check if you turned on "Allow less secure apps"

[image]